# How to pre-populate data in cache with spring and ehcache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have introduced Ehcache in my web application. It is working file when I try to populate the cache after server startup. But what I want is to populate my cache at the time of server startup. Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Here is the code where I call a Ehcache on a method to populate the cache after server get started.

```
@Transactional
@Cacheable(value="loadUserCache")
public List<UsersDTO> getAllUsers() {
    List<Users> users = userRepository.findAll();

    List<UsersDTO> usersDTO = new ArrayList<UsersDTO>(users.size());

    for (Users user : users) {
        UsersDTO userDTO = mapper.map(user, UsersDTO.class);
        usersDTO.add(userDTO);
    }
    return usersDTO;
}
```

This code is working correctly but the requirement is I want it to be done at the time of server startup.

What I try so far to achieve is

```
@Cacheable(value = "loadUserCache")
public void update() {
    List<Users> users = userRepository.findAll();
    for (Users user : users) {
        cacheManager.getCache("loadUserCache").put(user.getId(), user);
    }
}
```

Calling the method in `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing, at server startup, you need to trigger a process, and `@PostConstruct` is a good choice.

Comment: The issue I am facing is I can not populate the cache. I can see in the console that all records are fetching from the DB, but it is not being populated in the cache.

Comment: There is a disconnect between the two code samples. The first on will create a _single_ entry in the cache, default key -> list of users. The second will create multiple cache entries: user id -> user. Also, @Cacheable on a method that returns void makes no sense.

Comment: @LouisJacomet Then what should I do to achieve i.e. to pre-populate (at server startup) the cache, can you please suggest me something.